# PWM on voltage or power

Tags: pwm, sine

I try to implement a pure sine wave inverter based on PWM and using a microcontroller.

While things regarding PWM seemed simple, I am actually confused on the below aspects:

To my understanding PWM tries to simulate a waveform by fixed height and duration steps that overall keep the average of the simulated parameter as close as possible to the average of the original parameter wave form.

The question that arises now is what we want to simulate, the voltage or the power?

For example, if we simulate the voltage or the power and we have an incandescent lamp as a load, examining the luminosity of the lamp during its 50 Hz or better said 0.01 s period (as luminosity is equal for positive and negative voltages) we will see that the PWM better simulates the expected output when the reference parameter is power instead of voltage.

Different approaches may be valid for inductive loads but overall things should not be different.

So it seems to me that the parameter to take into consideration and simulate is the power (squared voltage) instead of the voltage itself.

So the question is: what is done by typical PWM pure sine wave inverters and what would be better to do in order to simulate as close as possible the effects of the pure sine wave?

Comment: Do you not have a PWM filter on the output??

Comment: The source provides voltage, but current and power are determined by the load.

Comment: Unless some super specific strange load, you want a VSC, producing voltage output. Current and power will handle itself.

Comment: I would like to avoid a filter, cause the load is a fixed size induction motor and by intuition it seems to me that it should work without filter (under conditions to find out)

Answer (score 2):

A sinewave inverter is typically used to produce an AC voltage should the AC mains power be unavailable. This can then unambiguously be used to deliver the same AC voltage to several independent loads sharing the same lines. And, of course, the inverter won't know what loads are connected or what one load might be taking in terms of power so, when you say this: -

> *we will see that the pwm better simulates the expected output when the
> reference parameter is power instead of voltage.*

You cannot be thinking of sinewave inverters of the type that dominate the market because, how could an inverter know what power is required by a certain load. For instance, a fridge turns on and off its compressor in order to regulate the internal fridge temperature and, how will the inverter know what part of the cycle the fridge is operating in.

So, what you say sounds like nonsense to me so, here's your opportunity to put things right and give more details about your assertion. You also say this: -

> *So it seems to me that the parameter to take into consideration and
> simulate is the power ( squared voltage ) instead of the voltage it
> self.*

Well, here's another problem, the power consumed of say a simple incandescent lamp is also a sinewave but, at twice the frequency of the voltage waveform so, how would that help especially if there are other loads connected that require the frequency to be close the AC mains frequency used in that country? Also, power isn't a waveform so how would you go about constructing it.

> *So the question is: what is done by typical pwm pure sine wave
> inverters and what would be better to do in order to simulate as close
> as possible the effects of the pure sine wave?*

Power is voltage multiplied by current. If you don't know the current profile that a certain appliance is meant to be taking, how can you possibly do anything else other than provide a sinewave voltage constructed by using PWM methods.